# How can I retrieve location info of a youtube video?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm writing an android app to play a youtube video. I want to play the video and, at the same time, to display the location info(latitude, longitude) in a map where the video was taken. I managed to play a video by using Youtube Player Android APIs, but cannot retrieve location info of the video.
Is there any way to get detailed info (including location) of a youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4234

It has been disabled for some time I'm afraid.

EDIT: well, not disabled completely, but still, this will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve `GEO / Where / Gml / Pos / latitude / longitude` but you can't get the information for every video, since youtube users don't publish or have published it for every video. even youtube don't give and/or have that information for every video. so, there is not guarantee.